# how to run command in another terminal in Linux script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

In Linux shell script I have to run few commands under another user but I am enable to.
Please advice some suggestions.

```
$ jumpto -T -u ...
```

after this command it enters in another terminal and I want to execute commands in that terminal through script please help

Comment: What is `jumpto` ? Are you trying to run things as another **user** or in another **terminal** ?

Answer (score 0):

`xterm -e "bash -c \"./script.sh; exec bash\"" &`

where `./script.sh` can be just a command.